# How can assign UIAlertAction Image and Change the Title Color as well

Tags: swift

[image: I want to achieve like this]I am trying to create an UIAlertAction that has black color text for the button and I want to assign image as well:

```
let alert = UIAlertController(title: nil,
                              message: nil,
                              preferredStyle: .actionSheet)
let image = UIImage(named: "actionSheetGallery")
let action = UIAlertAction(title: "Choose Picture From Gallery", style: .default, handler: selectFromGallery)

action.setValue(image, forKey: "image")

let image1 = UIImage(named: "actionSheetCamera")
let action1 = UIAlertAction(title: "Take Picture from Camera", style: .default, handler: takePhoto)
action1.setValue(image1, forKey: "image")

let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel",
                                 style: .cancel, handler: nil)

alert.addAction(action1)
alert.addAction(action)
alert.addAction(cancelAction)

self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

I can assign either image or text color, How can we assign both. 
and image background you can see is changed as well.

[image]

Comment: Do you have a mockup of what you want to achieve?

Comment: please check now I updated the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that `action1.setValue(image1, forKey: "image")` could be dangerous: Apple could reject your app as you're using a private api. It **could**, I used private api sometimes and nothing happened.

Anyway, if you want to change the text color you can set a tint color to the alert controller's view:

```
alert.view.tintColor = .orange // or whatever
```

If you really want to put an image, the image itself will inherit the tint color of the view (which by default is that blue). To avoid using tint color, you could get your image changing the render mode:

```
let image = UIImage(named: "actionSheetGallery")?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal)
```

Comment: From this I found the exact image but I need to change my title color as well.

Comment: You have to apply the tint color as I showed. For example `alert.view.tintColor = .black` to have black texts. Otherwise you can create your custom color using `UIColor` initializer

Comment: Yup It's working exactly. Thank you so much for this easy way

Comment: Be careful on using private api. The proper way to this stuff should be create a custom component.

Comment: Can I just assign the title text size as well?

Comment: Can you please let me know the custom component way as well?

Comment: Not sure about changing the text size, if it's possible you have to deal with other private apis. Custom component means basically that you have to create a view controller that acts like this alert controller.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191916/discussion-between-deviyani-swami-and-rico-crescenzio).

Answer (score 1):

This line is illegal:

```
action1.setValue(image1, forKey: "image")
```

A UIAlertAction cannot have an image. If you want to customize the appearance of an action sheet, create your own presented view controller (which is all an alert controller really is, after all).

Comment: What do you mean by *illegal*?

Comment: @LinusGeffarth  Well, look at the documented API for UIAlertAction. Do you see anything about images? No. I’m saying to the OP: You’re using key value coding to hack your way into a private API. That’s now biting you (and even if it weren’t it could get you rejected at the App Store). Don’t do it.

Answer (score 0):

Try below function

```
 func myAlert(){
    let refreshAlert = UIAlertController(title: "Unlike Article", message: "Are you sure you want to unlike this Article?", preferredStyle: UIAlertController.Style.alert)

    let cancel = UIAlertAction(title:  "CANCEL", style: .default, handler: { (action: UIAlertAction!) in

        return
    })

    let image = resizeImage(image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "twitter"), targetSize: CGSize(width: 25, height: 25))
    let unLike = UIAlertAction(title: "UNLIKE", style: .destructive, handler: { (action: UIAlertAction!) in


        return
    })
    unLike.setValue(image.withRenderingMode(UIImage.RenderingMode.alwaysOriginal), forKey: "image")
    refreshAlert.addAction(cancel)
    refreshAlert.addAction(unLike)
    refreshAlert.view.tintColor = UIColor.black
    self.present(refreshAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```